# convert java code to the sequence diagram in Enterprisse Architect

Tags: java, eclipse, reverse-engineering, enterprise-architect

is it possible the convert java code to the sequence diagram in Enterprisse Architect? if yes How?

Comment: Assuming you're referring to Sparx Systems Enterprise Architect, you might find this helpful.  http://blog.lieberlieber.com/2012/03/13/tutorial-nunit-and-sequence-diagram-recording-in-enterprise-architect-9-3/

Comment: This is a perfectly good question; I assume the people that closed it aren't familiar with the subject matter. The answer is that Enterprise Architect does not generate sequence diagrams from static analysis of code, only from execution traces. You will need to read the help pages on the Execution Analyzer.